# Using OpenAI custom environments

Tags: python, openai-gym

I have a file `rb.py` which is roughly structured like this:

```
import gym

def main():
   env = gym.make('ComplexMiniGolf-v0')
```

The issue is that if I create another file and do:

```
from rb import main
main()
```

The custom environment gets loaded and everything works. But if instead:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('ComplexMiniGolf-v0')
```

The custom environment cannot be found even though they load the exact same package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your environment in gym?

You could do it this way if your own environment is defined in the following structure:

```
myenv/
    __init__.py
    myenv.py
```

`myenv.py` contains the class for your environment. In `__init__.py` you put the following code:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(
    id='MyEnv-v0',
    entry_point='myenv.myenv:MyEnv',
)
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
import gym
import myenv
env = gym.make('MyEnv-v0')
```